# adding and retrieving objects from a list

Tags: java, list

My goal is to have a list of cars as an Object so that, I can retrieve a Car from that list. As well as get details of the cars. Can someone point me to the right direction

What I have done so far.

1. Create a class called Car and have the variables CarNum, carName, carPlate;
2. generated getters and setters for the variables and a toString as the carName
3. Create a class called CarCollection as follows

.

```
 public class CarCollection {
        private List<CarItem> mCarList;



        public void addVan(CarItem v) {
            mCarList.add(v);
        }

        public List<CarItem> getCarList() {
            return mCarList;
        }
```

The following test doesn't work. Why?

```
public class TestCarCollectionprocess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CarItem car1 = new CarItem();
        car1.setmCarName("Pedro");
        car1.setmCarNum(1);

        CarItem car2 = new CarItem();
        car2.setmCarName("Rene");
        car2.setmCarNum(2);

        CarCollection carList = new CarCollection();        
        carList.addCar(car1);
        carList.addCar(car2);
        System.out.println(carList.getCarList());
    } 
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: please provide what you got in output.

Comment: I don't see an addCar method in your CarCollection class and I don't see if you are fully constructing the private List<CarItem> mCarList;

Comment: Your should READ the exception you get. It tells exactly what and where the problem is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I see from your code, you should get `NullPointerException` in `addVan` method since you didn't initialize `List`, so change it like this:

```
 private List<CarItem> mCarList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a CarItem to the CarCollection's mCarList without ever instantiating the list so you should be getting a null reference exception.  In your carCollection class, create a constructor that sets

```
mCarList = new List<CarItem>();
```

Comment: no, IList is an interface, List is an implementation of the interface